# compare input timestamp with interval, get operator error

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have a Java code to `trigger` SQL query, I need to compare with input time and input time plus one hour, not sure what is wrong here for it is working on my SQL client.

I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select count(*) from
>   transaction where timestamp > ? AND timestamp < (? + INTERVAL '1 HOUR'
>   - INTERVAL '120')]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   timestamp with time zone < interval

The Java code:

```
static final String SQL_QUERY_TO_FETCH_TRANSACTION_COUNT = "select count(*) from %s where timestamp > :timestamp AND " +
        "timestamp < (:timestamp + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' - INTERVAL '%s')";


public Transactions getTransactionsAfterTime(Timestamp lastReadTimestamp, int maxRecords) throws SQLException {
        DatabaseRecordMapper transactionRecordMapper = DatabaseRecordMapper.builder().tableName(TRANSACTION).build();
        SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("timestamp", lastReadTimestamp);
        final String sqlToFetchTransactionCount =
                String.format(SQL_QUERY_TO_FETCH_TRANSACTION_COUNT, TRANSACTION,
                        Integer.toString(TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS));
```

Comment: Please show us which bind values you are passing and how

Comment: the bind value is "2018-12-12T21:00:00.000Z"

Comment: pass in way has updated

Answer (score 0):

You always have to specify a unit with an `interval` literal, `"120"` alone isn't enough.

You can remove the ambiguity with a type cast. Change

```
timestamp < (? + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' - INTERVAL '120')
```

to

```
timestamp < (?::timestamptz + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' - INTERVAL '120')]
```